# i am making a post request to send a array of list in request body but i am getting error NETWORK REQUEST FAILED again and again in react native

Tags: ios, react-native

I am making a post request to send a array of list in request body but i am getting error "NETWORK REQUEST FAILED" again and again in react native. some piece of code is mentioned below.

```
var params = {
        grocery_list_name: 'MY_grocery_LIST',
        items: [{
            "product":"320",
            "price" : "6.99",
            "quantity" : "2",
            "special_deal":"1",
            "template":"1"
          },{
            "product":"321",
            "price" : "7.99",
            "quantity" : "3",
            "special_deal":"2",
            "template":"2"
          },]
        };
try {return fetch(URL, { method: 'POST', headers: {
              'Authorization': 'bearer AtE9slkuafhebbjKkYe0tTimMZc',
              'Content-Type': 'application/json'},
            body: JSON.stringify(params),})
            .then(function(response){
            console.log(response);
            return response.json();
          })
        } catch (error) {
          console.error(error);
        } finally {  }
```

Comment: What exactly is the URL? On iOS url must be https. To allow http requests, you have to change permissions in Info.plist

Comment: @niceman , hiii
yes ,URL is https.